# Internet Explorer 9 update fails on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, updates, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to install Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit via Windows Update, but always get the same error: 800F081E.

I have all recent updates installed and no antivirus software that might block the installation.

Prior to updating I had Internet Explorer 9 32-bit installed from the Windows web site; I removed that update before installation.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know its a chore, but i suggest going through all the suggestions on this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2409098) and seeing if they solve the issue.

> When you try to install Internet Explorer 9, you may receive an
>   error message and cannot install Internet Explorer 9. There are
>   various causes for installation problems. This article describes four
>   common troubleshooting methods.
>
> - Method 1: Meet the minimum operating system requirement of the
>     Internet Explorer 9 installation
> - Method 2: Install required    software and components
> - Method 3: Complete the installation of    other updates
> - Method 4: Temporarily disable spyware and    anti-virus software

Comment: no, that is not, I tried all methods, in 3) x64 updates are not suitable to my computer

Comment: that was strange but after I manually downloaded IE9-Windows7-x64-enu.exe and launched it with windows restart IE installed at last